# В чём разница и почему может этот код не работать?

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Я уже совсем не понимаю почему не работает.
Вот есть скрипт. Он работает:

```
<?php
    $ses = $_GET['PHPSESSID'];

    $params = array();

    $params['no_first'] = $_GET['no_first'];
    $params['PHPSESSID']= $_GET['PHPSESSID'];
    $params['radio1'] = $_GET['radio1'];

    $url = "https://сайт/proccess2.php?PHPSESSID=".$ses;

    $c = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID='.$ses);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);

    $result = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    file_put_contents('test.php', iconv("WINDOWS-1251", "UTF-8", $result));

    echo "<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' content ='0;URL=https://мой_сайт/test.php?PHPSESSID=".$ses."'></head></html>";
?>
```

А когда передаю в curl в тело пост запроса сразу переменную $_GET, запрос отправляется, он валидный, ответ приходит, но в тесте ответы не засчитываются:

```
<?php
    $ses = $_GET['PHPSESSID'];

    $url = "https://сайт/proccess2.php?PHPSESSID=".$ses;

    $c = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_COOKIE, 'PHPSESSID='.$ses);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_GET);

    $result = curl_exec($c);
    curl_close($c);

    file_put_contents('test.php', iconv("WINDOWS-1251", "UTF-8", $result));

    echo "<html><head><META HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' content ='0;URL=https://мой_сайт/test.php?PHPSESSID=".$ses."'></head></html>";
?>
```

Comment: В каком таком тесте?

Comment: ну в общем, для автоматизации теста, мой сервис получает оригинальную страницу, показывает мне, на хостинге свой обработчик, который принимает ответ, отправляет его оригинальному сайту, и полученный результат опять показывает мне. При первом варианте мне засчитываются ответы правльные, а во втором - в результате всё по нулям

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cURL - низкоуровневый в данном примере.
Когда ты напрямую передаешь туда тип данных array чем и является $_GET. Думаю тут сложно спорить что GET это массив.

То в POST FIELDS пишется строка, а что будет если массив привести к строке? Правильно строка *Array*.

**Как решить твою проблему и в каком направлении думать**
1. Зависит от того куда отправляет cURL запрос, там требуют определенный формат данных будь то json, xml, html или любой другой. Вот его тебе и нужно послать который требуется.
2. Если ты сам эти запросы отправляешь и пересылаешь, самое простое для тебя будет это при отправке заворачивать массив в *json_encode*, а где обрабатываешь, пиши *json_decode* и у тебя не будет никаких проблем.

Comment: Вы вообще разницу в коде видите? Автор вопроса в обоих случаях передаёт массив.

Comment: вот я о том же. Я проверял содержимое переменной $params и $_GET с помощью var_dumps(); Результат полностью совпадает

Comment: Когда я "вручную" заполняю массив $params, то корректно всё работает, а когда готовый передаю, то не получается нужного результата

Comment: будем честны это очень плохой код и я его даже не читаю. Исходя из своей практики, знаю что http текстовый протокол, post fields пишутся в тело запроса. Если массив привести к строке, будет array. То что у его там сработало или нет - это явно баг. Что не удивительно исходя из такого кода.

Comment: (https://intop24.ru/article_20.php) Вот отсюда я взял пример, там в POSTFIELDS передаётся массив

Comment: автор, хватит удалять свои комментарии. Нужно думать головой. Допустим есть пример с массивом и он работает, в какой формат cURL преобразует массив? Я всегда ручками для каждого формата делаю обертки, и понимаю что происходит. Тут же магия.

Comment: хорошо, можно тогда узнать как корректно массив к строке привести?

Comment: самые популярные json и xml. В твоем случае json будет лучше.

Comment: Ну в json я оберну, а тот сайт с которым я взаимодействую поймёт это?

Comment: у меня нет к нему доступа

Comment: Так нужно документацию почитать или узнать с каким форматом данных он работает.

Comment: да, я посмотрел, postfields принимает string. Как по умолчанию он приводит неявно array в string?

Comment: любой массив при приведений к string просто слово array

Comment: ух, я и не знал, странно, почему тогда первый вариант работал. Ладно, спасибо, буду разбираться